# Can I buy a Walmart gift card using a Walmart egift card?

Tags: united-states, gift-card

I received a $25 walmart egift card, but I needed a physical card for purchase in store (I have no smartphone or printer to bring the egift card to the store). So I used the $25 Walmart egift card to buy a $25 physical gift card on Walmart.com, but the order was cancelled,

> because your payment could not be verified

and

> due to an error processing payment information

is it because

- the processing system takes out $1 out of the egift card to verify it, and the remaining $24 not enough to cover the purchase, or
- Walmart doesn't allow using its egift card to buy its gift card, or
- ...?

Their customer service is unable to explain why. So I have to ask if someone knows about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, gift cards can't be used to buy gift cards. Whether that's true for Walmart will be in ths contract you implicitly accept by using the card; the details should be on their website somewhere.

Comment: I'm assuming your are buying perishable goods? Because you can order online and pickup in store with most of their products. But I agree with Keshlam, it is kind of counter productive to use a giftcard to buy a giftcard.

Comment: Also, they may allow you to use your egift card code in store. They will have to manually enter it in of course. I am not 100% sure but basically cashiers would scan the barcode of the egift card printout, but what if the barcode is not scanning? They would have to have an option to manually enter it in. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

Many e-commerce stores don't permit using a gift card to purchase another gift card for the same store. I don't, however, see it expressly noted in their [Terms and Conditions](http://help.walmart.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57/~/gift-card-terms-and-conditions). The T&C page also lists an email and phone # dedicated to gift card purchasing questions, so you may want to ask them rather than in-store customer service or the general help contact information.

[Their FAQ](http://help.walmart.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/131) does state that you can print the eGift card and take it into a store with you to redeem. Because you don't have a printer, the easiest solution may be to ask a friend to print it for you. Staying at a hotel anytime soon? You could use the business center to print it. Or, go to a library and print it (what is it now, $0.10 per page?)

Their T&C page also states that you can combine gift cards by using multiple gift cards to purchase a single gift card. This can probably only be done in-store as it refers to them as gift cards rather than eGift cards.

> Consolidating Walmart Gift Cards. If you have two or more Walmart Gift Cards, you can consolidate them by using them to purchase one new Walmart Gift Card that has a balance equal to the sum total of the Walmart Gift Cards you currently have.

Answer (score 2):

You can't buy a gift card with another gift card online, but you certainly can in store (go to customer service). You can also use your e-gift card at the register. Even if it doesn't have a bar code, the cashier can simply key in the numbers. You don't have to print it out either, simply show the cashier the card on your phone.